# Identifying a bulb from a 1969 built light fitting

Tags: lighting

I came across this light bulb socket in a piece of furniture built in 1969 in America. It's 2014 and I'm in Britain so frankly I have no idea. It's right down inside the thing so this is the best photo I can get.

[image: interior light bulb fitting]

I've worked with American pieces before but I don't recognise this kind of fitting. It doesn't seem to be threaded as an Edison Screw bulb usually is. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not threaded.  Stick your hand down there to the ceramic part.  It looks like a totally standard Edison base, if threaded.

Comment: It does to me too but the inside surface of the socket is completely smooth. It's about the right size for an E27 but no threading and I was wondering if it might be something that has fallen into disuse. I was considering popping an E27/E26 in first and letting gravity hold it in but I don't want to risk it without an opinion.

Comment: What is the internal diameter of the socket? In what orientation is the fixture intended for use? Could it be intended for specialized use?

Answer (score 1):

I've owned a light socket exactly like that one - identical in size to an E27 but totally lacking in internal threads. Mine was simply a manufacturing screwup - the rest of the sockets on the shelf, with the same product number, had the expected internal threads. I got mine all the way home and installed before I noticed the flaw. The store was quite happy to exchange it for a "real" socket that worked.

Replacing that socket with a normal threaded E17 socket is an easy job.